# Renaming all files in a folder with a prefix and in ascending order

Tags: bash, shell, unix

How does one rename

```
random_files.jpg
that\ may\ contain\ spaces.jpg
and_differ_in_extensions.mp4
```

to

```
PREFIX_1.jpg
PREFIX_2.jpg
PREFIX_3.mp4
```

via bash script? More formally, how do I rename all files in a directory into an ordered list of form `PREFIX_N.ext` where `.ext` is preserved from the original filename.

My attempt below

```
for f in *; do 
    [[ -f "$f" ]] && mv "$f" "PREFIX_$f"
done
```

changes only prefixes.

Comment: Switching to the directory and running: `for f in *; do [[ -f "$f" ]] && mv "$f" "PREFIX_$f"; done` changes prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the files using `*`, and then access them with a quoted var to preserve all the special characters.

You can then use parameter expansion to remove the start of the file up to `.`, and append that to your new filename.

```
x=1;for i in *;do [[ -f "$i" ]] && mv "$i" "PREFIX_$((x++)).${i##*.}";done
```

If you know x isn't already set though you can remove the assignment at the start and change `$((x++))` to `$((++x))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in a for loop using `find`:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
   ext="${file##*.}"
   echo mv "$file" "PREFIX_$((++i)).$ext"
done < <(find . -type f -name '*.*' -maxdepth 1 -print0)
```

Once satisfied with the output, remove `echo` before `mv` command.

Comment: I like the "echo mv ..." technique to test a script before running it.